# How to verify a DataFrame with a DataFrame of conditions?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am looking for a solution for a problem. I have an excel file that has to fit a special setup, so it has to have specific columns and the rows have to have a specific range for the numbers.

So would it be possible to do a copy of my excel file and use this copy as a template? In this template I would replace all numbers with a string that represents a condition for a number that is exactly at this position (cell) in another excel file.

Let's say I have this dataframe of an excel file:

```
|headline|headline2|headline3|
|--------|---------|---------|
|30      |1.0      |abc      |
|80      |0.5      |cda      |
|--------|---------|---------|
```

Would it be possible to load another file, that is like a template of conditions, so that I can verify the data of the DataFrame above?
The template would look like this DataFrame here:

```
|headline  |headline2|headline3|
|----------|---------|---------|
|>0 & <100 |>0 & <1  |string   |
|>0 & <100 |>0 & <1  |string   |
|----------|---------|---------|
```

Loading my excel file that needs to be verified and comparing it with my template would give me a new DataFrame that holds only wrong entries. Like a number is greater than 100, or it is a string instead of an integer.

Maybe it is possible to just write a group name into a cell of the template, so that the program knows what condition is needed. Then I could enter a specific group into my template. Then I could mix these groups in different cells of my template.

```
|headline|headline2|headline3|
|--------|---------|---------|
|group1  |group2   |group3   |
|group3  |group2   |group2   |
|--------|---------|---------|
```

Somewhere a group could be defined like this:

```
group1 = >0 & <100
group2 = >0 & <1
group3 = string
```

Comment: I don't have experience using it but this looks like a job for [pd.eval](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.eval.html#pandas.eval).